# passing java arraylist object from R

Tags: java, r, arraylist

I am a freshman,hehe
there are more questions...
how can i creat a java-class type object in R
for example ,there is a java class definition below:

---

```
public class Bond{
  public String secid;
  public int paycycle;
  public float couprate;
  public Date vdate;

  public Bond(String secid,int paycycle,float couprate,Date vdate)
    {
        this.secid = secid;
        this.paycycle = paycycle;
        this.couprate = couprate;
        this.vdate = vdate;

    }
}
```

---

I intend to passing a Bond object to java function,actually,it's ArrayList object,i have no idea how to acheive,can you give me some idea,thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass an object as an argument to Java method, then you need to create this object as Java object with `.jnew`. On the R side you can use a list to represent the fields of a Java object, but you can't pass such object to Java via `.jcall`.

Considering your comment below, maybe you need to rethink your approach to the problem you are trying to solve. Think about which parts of the solution have to be coded in Java and which in R. Then think how you can interface these two parts with minimal amount of coupling. You may be able to code your complete solution in Java, or pass the data between Java and R via text file instead of trying to create solution which passes objects back and forth between different languages. If this works, you don't need rJava.

The way I see it, rJava is primarily used when you want to take advantage of some algorithms or methods implemented in Java while calling them from R. The data is passed back and forth as primitives or arrays of primitives, not as custom objects.

Comment: yeah,I tried that yesterday,I got that it is too complicated to operate a java class object in R,I knew how to convert it to java object,but how to reconvert it?
wow,I am a little bit frustrated..